# what is the difference between Write, WriteChar and WriteChars Methods from DataOutputStream class in java?

Tags: java

what is the difference between Write, WriteChar and WriteChars Methods in java?

I am Writing to output and i am seeing three methods for it , Kindly which method to use in what condition?

Comment: What is the class those mentioned methods belong to?

Comment: DataOutputStream class

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: No , I am not from java background but read some google sites and it was not clear to me so I asked.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation:

- write( int b ) writes b value as byte
- writeChar( int c ) writes c value as char
- writeChars( String s ) writes s as list of chars

Comment: we can have  string also in writeChar()?

Comment: No, writeChar() takes only int values. Use writeChars() since it should work with any string size.

Comment: if i am using writeChars() i am getting spaces after each letter. how to overcome that?